# How can I insert a line of text above the occurence of a specific text in a long R Script?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have been looking for a solution to this problem but could not find a practical one.
I have a long R script (more than 1500 lines).

I have the following text which repeats itself several times in the Script:

```
df00$StartDate
```

I need to add the following line of text just above it (everywhere where it occurs):

```
df00$`MealPlan` <- sub('\n.*', '', output3$`Your choices`)
```

Is there an efficient way to do this instead of scrolling through the Script and manually pasting that new line of code?

Comment: search and replace ?

Comment: I gave it a try but it doesn't work. It merges both lines into one single line.

Comment: you'll need to insert a carriage return \n after the first line. It is strange though that you need to do the same thing many times...

Comment: This is because the Script is like a set of scripts combined into one single script.

Comment: it just seemed to me like a function oculd have been created to run on different data to save some lines of code ;-)

Comment: I would recommend using script editors (e.g., notepad ++ ) that have many tools to manipulate scripts.

Comment: @Cath Where do I insert the \n? Inside the Search and Replace box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CTRL+F` search for `df00$StartDate`, then click "All", then start editing, the edit will be done for all selected rows at the same time.

See screenshot, you will see a multiline cursor at the end of each line:

[image]

[2015-05-06: RStudio v0.99 Preview: More Editor Enhancements](https://blog.rstudio.com/2015/05/06/rstudio-v0-99-preview-more-editor-enhancements/)